# Data Structure for storing Vertex Attributes

Tags: c++, opengl, data-structures, stl

I need to implement a structure which stores vertices by the attributes. For example every vertex has an attribute like "Normals" or "Position" "Colors" etc., and they can be accessed by their names.

```
VertexStructure vstruct;
AttribStream posStream = vstruct.CreateNewAttributeStream("Position",Vec3<double>);
posStream.push_back(Vec3<double>(23.5,12.5,11.3));

AttribStream normalStream = vstruct.CreateNewAttributeStream("Normals",Vec3<double>);
normalStream.push_back(Vec3<double>(0.03,0.02,0.18));

AttribStream indexStream = vstruct.CreateNewAttribStream("Indices",int);
indexStream.push_back(23);

std::cout << indexStream.size() << "," << normalStream.size() << posStream.size() << std::endl;
```

Now one easy way I can do it is to create an enum with pre-defined data types, like how OpenGL does it. Like:

```
enum {
 DOUBLE = 0,
 FLOAT,
 INT,
};

 AttribStream posStream = vstruct.CreateNewAttributeStream("Position",DOUBLE,3);
 posStream.push_back_vec3d(23.5,12.5,11.3);
```

But, it is very verbose and I have to create an enum for every possible data type and have separate functions for each data type to push back new elements.

Another possible way is using Abstract classes. But even that doesn't guarantee type-safety (unless using RTTI) and involves casting and also very hard to abstract it. Also, **there is no way to create a generic 'push_back'**, so I need to create specialized functions for every type.

```
class PX_STREAMBase
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    PX_STREAMBase( T val) : value_type(typeid(T)),
    value_size(sizeof(val))
    {};

    virtual size_t bytes() const = 0;
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual const void* data() const = 0;

    const std::type_info& value_type;
    const std::size_t value_size;

private:


};

template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container =  std::vector> class PX_STREAM;
template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container>
class PX_STREAM : public PX_STREAMBase {
public:
    PX_STREAM() :
    PX_STREAMBase( T())
    {}

    size_t bytes() const {
        return vec.size() * value_size;
    }
    size_t size() const {
        return vec.size();
    }
    const void* data() const {
        return vec.data();
    }
private:


    Container<T, std::allocator<T> > vec;
};
```

Lastly, there is using a char array struct as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391299/cast-char-array-struct-vector-to-a-pod-vector/21392409)
So, what is the best way to create a structure that abstracts the vector and can hold an attribute stream of any type?

Comment: You are going overboard with this: `VEC2_DOUBLE`. First of all, double-precision vertex attributes are a GL4 feature; in fact, D3D11 does not even support them. What you ought to do is store the base component type and the number of components as two separate properties. For instance you have 2 `GLdouble` components in such an attribute. Count = 2, Component = GLdouble. Double-precision is not particularly useful for rendering.

Comment: The data isn't supposed to be OpenGL compatible. I've just used it as an example. But you're right.

Comment: Well, you mentioned *"like how OpenGL does it"* in your question. And this is not actually how GL does it. While it is true that GL has `DOUBLE_VEC2` as a constant enum, that is used to [describe the type of a GLSL variable](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGetActiveUniform.xml). You never tell GL about a vertex attribute using that enum, it is always done by telling GL the underlying data type and the number of components. If you want to do it like GL does, then you would follow that model.

Comment: Gotcha. But still, that means POD structs have to be broken into individual attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this looks like you're trying to create a struct to store data for a 3D model. Vertex coordinates and normals. Honestly, I think you're just trying to make it to fancy. A struct with a pair `vec3<double>`s that store the positions and normals (actually, these should be floats if you want to use them in openGL as most graphics cards have terrible support for double precision floats), and then whatever other data your system is storing for it's models. You use a vector of this structure and it keeps all of the information for any given vertex together.

If you really need to keep all of the data separate, I've not seen a system that has such a need yet but my experience is still more limited than I would like, then create a struct or class that just has a number of vectors that each contains a vec3 or whatever datatype you need for that particular structure. Most systems know what kind of data they're going to be looking at for their models, so implementing these structures statically shouldn't be a problem. For the final vertex data, you just create a structure that contains a number of indices for the separate components that make up a particular vertex.

Is there a reason a much simpler system like:

```
class Model
{
private:
    //These vectors serve just to hold all of the data for all of your vertices
    vector<vec3<float> > positions;
    vector<vec3<float> > normals;
    vector<vec3<float> > colors;

    //This struct holds indices to the vectors above
    struct Vertex
    {
        int position;
        int normal;
        int color;
    };

    //Holds a list of all of your vertices, but allows you to pair different positions with different normals, etc...
    vector<Vertex> vertices;

    //Holds a list of indices from vertices that are your points to draw.
    vector<int> drawPoints;
public:
    //constructor, destructor, and accessors to add elements to your various elements.
};
```

wouldn't work?

Comment: If it's just a few attributes, that would be very easy. But this case, each vertex probably has 25-30 attributes (not all of them are for rendering, most are for animation and other metadata) and they're loaded dynamically.

Comment: @rwb You may be better off still just doing the class as I have it noted: just filling out all of the attributes that are used and leaving the remaining vectors empty (or possibly using a pointer and not even constructing the vector if it's not needed). Unless you don't even know the types that each attribute would take and those are assigned at run time, at which point god bless you sir because you are a braver man than I. :)